# rsync glitches with -X (extended attributes) flag

Tags: filesystems, rsync

When I rsync files from ext4 file system to btrfs with the following set of flags:

```
rsync --update -DHAXErlptgo
```

the first copy of the backaped directory is done OK, but when this same command is repeated (for updating), even immediately,  there are errors related to extended attributes. If the -X flag is not used, there are no errors. Here what errors look like (there are more of them just for one /etc directory):

```
rsync: get_xattr_names: llistxattr(""/mnt/backup/rootdir/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/winbindd.service"",1024) failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: get_xattr_names: llistxattr(""/mnt/backup/rootdir/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/zfs.target"",1024) failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: get_xattr_names: llistxattr(""/mnt/backup/rootdir/etc/systemd/system/timers.target.wants/backup.timer"",1024) failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: get_xattr_names: llistxattr(""/mnt/backup/rootdir/etc/systemd/system/timers.target.wants/ntpsync.timer"",1024) failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

Could someone advise please why those errors are happen and how to get rid of them without excluding -X flag?

Thanks.

UPDATE: In other case errors happen even during the first copy:

```
rsync: failed to set times on "/mnt/backup/rootdir/root/.cache/sessions/thumbs-hostname:0": Invalid argument (22)
rsync: recv_generator: failed to stat "/mnt/backup/rootdir/root/.cache/sessions/thumbs-hostname:0/Default.png": Not a directory (20)
rsync: failed to set times on "/mnt/backup/rootdir/root/.cache/sessions/thumbs-hostname:0": Invalid argument (22)
rsync: recv_generator: failed to stat "/mnt/backup/rootdir/root/.cache/sessions/thumbs-hostname:0/Default.png": Not a directory (20)
rsync: get_acl: sys_acl_get_file(root/.cache/sessions/.xfce4-session-hostname:0.yON2Lj, ACL_TYPE_ACCESS): No such file or directory (2)
```

Comment: Do the extended attributes exist after the first run? Use `getfattr -d` on a file to dump extended attributes. Also consider e.g. https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Project_ideas#Unlimited_extended_attributes.

Comment: @Michael With other directory errors happen even during the first run (examples in the question's update)